# how to add items to shopping cart without adding button just on click on the picture

Tags: javascript, jquery

Recently i have been doing my own shopping cart but i have a problem , i don't want to add "add to cart" button on the item , i want to add items to the shopping cart by clicking on the items pictures; in the first click adding to cart and in the second one remove it from the cart .

I used this code but it does not work it needs a button;

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#submitbutton').click(function(e) {
        var pos = $('#inputid').val();
        alert(pos);
        return false;
    });
});
```

thanks for advice

Comment: how about you bind a click event on the picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just treat items element as a button and bind click event on them! On click add item to cart and set a data attribute flag to that item. So, next time you can check whether it is in added to cart or not.

e.g:

**HTML**

```
...
<li class="item" data-id="123">
    <img src="..." title="Product title">
</li>
...
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on('click', '.item', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var $cart = $('#cart');
    var item_identifier = $this.data('id');

    // If item is in cart already, then remove
    if ($this.data('in-cart')==='yes'
        && $cart.find('li[data-id="' + item_identifier + '"]').length > 0) {
        // Script to remove from cart
        return
    }

    // else add to cart
    $this.data('in-cart', 'yes');
    var to_cart = $('li').data('id', item_identifier).html($this.html());
    $cart.append(to_cart);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="item" item-id="123">
  <img src="<path to item image>">
</div>

jQuery(".item").click(function  () {
  var itemId = jQuery(this).attr("item-id");
  //write logic to add item to shopping cart by item id
})
```

Code above explains how it can be achieved. selector can be changed to ".item > img" if you want to trigger on clicking the image rather than div.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to picture, then write jquery script on that class on click, plus add a custom attribute to the image containing the item srno

or

add a link button with link containing item srno ,on click post it then add it to the cart begind the scenes

or
.
.
.
.
if you want more,just ask

Answer (score 0):

Check out these references

https://api.jquery.com/click/

https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

https://api.jquery.com/remove/

I would do a click event and target the items picture to add the item to the cart and then do a ".dblclick" on the item picture to ".remove" the same item from the cart.

Just one of many ways of accomplishing what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#target" ).toggle(function() {
  alert( "First handler for .toggle() called." );
}, function() {
  alert( "Second handler for .toggle() called." );
});
```

Use toggle, it will give you scope to write to function one for add and another for remove.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.cart_item').click(function () {

            alert($(this).attr('image_id'))
        });

 });  
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="a.png" image_id="id_1" class="cart_item">
<img src="a.png" image_id="id_2"    class="cart_item">
    <img src="a.png" image_id="id_3"    class="cart_item">
    <img src="a.png" image_id="id_4"    class="cart_item">
    <img src="a.png" image_id="id_5"    class="cart_item">

</body>
</html>
```